# How to remove colon(:) on longtable suffix caption

Tags: tables, captions, longtable

Using `svmono` package and `\renewcommand\tablename\{Tab.}`.  When I use table, the caption shows “Tab.1 Bah Bah”. But if I use longtable, the caption shows “Tab.2: Bah bah”.

How to remove colon as “Tab 2 Bah bah”.

Many Thank

Answer (score 4):

You have to modify `\LT@makecaption`. Add this to the preamble of your LaTeX document:

```
\makeatletter
\def\LT@makecaption#1#2#3{%
  \LT@mcol\LT@cols c{\hbox to\z@{\hss\parbox[t]\LTcapwidth{%
    \sbox\@tempboxa{#1{#2 }#3}%
    \ifdim\wd\@tempboxa>\hsize
      #1{#2 }#3%
    \else
      \hbox to\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
    \fi
    \endgraf\vskip\baselineskip}%
  \hss}}}
\makeatother
```