# remove colon from table name

Tags: tables, captions, longtable

I'm using two-column article document class. Long table Name is displayed in the following format:

> Table 1: table caption goes here.

But I want to change in this way:

> Table 1 table caption goes here

on the other words, I want to remove colon (:).

How can I do it?

I have to say that I tried the following topic: [How to remove colon(:) on longtable suffix caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14134/how-to-remove-colon-on-longtable-suffix-caption)
and I place that code below `documentclass[a4paper]{article}` and some `\usepakage...`
but it did not work out.

My template is as follows:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
    \usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
    \begin{document}

    \title{Title}
    \author{author}
    \linespread{1.6}
    \renewenvironment{abstract}{%
      \noindent\bfseries\abstractname:\normalfont}{}

    \maketitle
    \begin{abstract}
    \end{abstract}
    \section{Introduction}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Does adding the following to your preamble help `\usepackage[labelsep=space]{caption}`?

Comment: It can remove : but the caption is placed at the bottom of it instead of at the top.

Comment: If you place the caption before the tabular it will be placed on top of the table. See the example in my answer.

Comment: when I test your first solution I accidentally placed it before the tabular : \begin{table*}[!t] \caption{My caption.} \label{tableII}

Comment: I don't understand. Could you please try to be clearer?

Comment: @N.N.: Dear N.N. I placed caption before the tabular but the caption is still below the table. I'm using table* rather than table.

Comment: Mico answered this in the comments below his answer. If you still cannot solve the problem I suggest you make an MWE and post a new question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I suggest you load the package `caption` with the following option:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=space}
```

If you want this setting, i.e., a space instead of a colon, to apply to `figure` environments as well, you'd just remove the `[table]` option from the `\captionsetup` command.

A separate issue: To get the caption to print *above* the body of the float, all you need to do is to specify the caption (and its label, if any) *after* the `\begin{table/figure}` command but *before* starting a tabular environment and/or before including some external graphics file.

Comment: I placed my caption before \begin{table} but the problem has not solved.!! but I have to say that I'm using \begin{table*}[!t]

Comment: You must place the `\caption` command *after* the `\begin{table}` command but *before* any `\begin{tabular}` (or tabular*, tabularx, ...) instructions. (Placing the caption command before the start of the float is going to generate wildly unpredictable results.) Incidentally, using the table* and figure* environments only make sense in a two-column document (when you want a float that spans both columns of text). I'm editing my answer to clarify this point.

Answer (score 9):

Use the `caption` package with the `labelsep=space` option to achieve this.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[labelsep=space]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{An example of a table}
\begin{tabular}{ l c r }
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I posted my answer, in substance identical to yours, only a few seconds after you posted your answer. Would you want me to delete it?

Comment: @Mico You mention an aspect (that you can set the option per enviroment instead of globally) that I don't mention in my answer (or my initial comment to the question) so I think your answer is justified.