# Delete ":" in the caption of figure and tables

Tags: tables, floats, captions

Each time I cite a table or figure, the caption is preceded by ".:"
Example: `Figure 1.: The proposed approach`, `Table 2.: Mobile apps categories`. How can I delete ":".
I'm using Taylor and Francis template:

```
\documentclass[]{interact}
\usepackage[labelsep=space]{caption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{notation}{Notation}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

Appreciate your help

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28205/remove-colon-from-table-name

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! Somewhere in your document preamble you declare that you like to have such delimiter betwee caption label and text. Because you not provide an example which recreate your problem, we can't say what is cause of your problem.

Comment: I'm using Taylor & Francis template. `\documentclass[]{interact}`

Comment: I used `\usepackage[labelsep=space]{caption}`, and that worked.

Answer (score 2):

The `interact` class is not compatible with `caption`: you indeed get the warning

```
Package caption Warning: Unknown document class (or package),
(caption)                standard defaults will be used.
```

If I remove the calls to `caption` and `subcaption`, I get

[image]

which is the style the class requests. Using `caption` would override this style and your manuscript will be likely rejected for not being conformant to the publisher's preferences.

If you need subfigures or subtables, use `subfig`, calling it

```
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
```

and use the package defined syntax for subfloats.